# tag: hol or higher-order-logic

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

We now have [higher-order-logic](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/higher-order-logic) and [hol](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hol). Probably one should be canonical, and the other one be [a tag synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms).

I suggest to use `hol`, as it is shorter and more likely what people will type.

Comment: So no synonyms?

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to reserve `hol` for the family of provers, and `higher-order-logic` for the foundations of mathematics?

Comment: @GuyCoder what about HOL-light or Isabelle/HOL, for example? Restricting to HOL4 (?) is too narrow imo.

Comment: I think there are certainly questions that apply to all provers of that family, like https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/154/how-can-all-functions-be-total-in-isabelle, and I think [hol] is a good tag for them. But of course the concrete provers deserve their own tags as well…

Comment: I agree with Joachim that [hol] can apply to questions of different proof assistants. Like the other question about totality, it deserves [isabelle] and [hol]. A similar question could be asked with a focus on (or rather with an example in) HOL-light and tagged [hol-light] and [hol].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be [higher-order-logic](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/higher-order-logic) and we can make [hol](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hol) a synonym [for this reason](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/28/5).

Comment: I wonder if `hol` is so much the acronym that's actually pronounced as such that different considerations apply, but I guess as long as there are synonyms it doesn't matter that much

Comment: Perhaps you can quote the reason here as well? :)

Comment: @TheAmplitwist good idea. The quality standards on Meta expected for Meta aren't the same as for Main (for example for link-only answers) but it would still be a better answer if I added more here.

Comment: I agree with the comments attached to the original question: we should distinguish the logic from the systems implementing the logic.  I'd suggest using `higher-order-logic` for the former, and then things along the lines of `hol4`, `hot-light`, `hol-family`.

Comment: `hol-light` rather than `hot-light` (auto-correct!).  `isabelle-hol` would be another system tag of course.  Then we get to start the debate on whether or not Isabelle/HOL is in the HOL family  :)